# Convert cURL to Guzzle Post sending json data

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I have this cURL command that I need to convert to PHP using Guzzle 7. I've have been researching this for a few (well, more than a few) days and getting nowhere fast. The cURL command uses the Simpli.fi api to create an organization under the parent org.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "X-App-Key: xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxxx" -H "X-User-Key: xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxxx" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "organization": {
          "name": "My New Organization",
          "parent_id": "5786",
          "custom_id": "<Put your organization identifier here or omit this optional field>"
        }
      }' \
  "https://app.simpli.fi/api/organizations"
```

I was able to convert it using this website but it doesn't use Guzzle: https://onlinedevtools.in/curl
Here's what it gave me:

```
include('vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php');
Requests::register_autoloader();
$headers = array(
    'X-App-Key' => 'xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxxx',
    'X-User-Key' => 'xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxxx',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
);
$data = '{\n        "organization": {\n          "name": "My New Organization",\n          "parent_id": "5786",\n          "custom_id": "<Put your organization identifier here or omit this optional field>"\n        }\n      }';
$response = Requests::post('https://app.simpli.fi/api/organizations', $headers, $data);
```

Here's what I've tried so far aside from the converted code above:

```
    public static function createOrganization()
    {
        self::init();

        $client = new Client(['debug' => true]);

        $request = $client->request('POST',
            self::$baseUrl.'/organizations', [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'data',
                    'contents' => "{'organization':{'name':'Pete's Pet Pagoda','parent_id':'1052385'}}",
                ],
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'x-app-key'   => self::$appKey,
                'x-user-key'  => self::$userKey,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]);

        dd($response = $request->getStatusCode());
    }
```

I'm getting quite a few different errors however this is the latest:

curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there something missing?

UPDATE: After further research into this issue and chatting with a developer on the Laracast Slack channel, I've come to learn that this is a bug with the `['debug' => true]` option when running on a Windows system and is described on this GITHUB page: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1413
I'm running on a Windows 10 Pro system. I corrected it on my end by changing the debug option to use fopen() like this:

```
'debug' => fopen('php://stderr', 'w'),
```

I use PHPStorm. It suggested using the 'wb' to make it binary safe. After changing it, the post requests worked fine.

Comment: Side note: `{'organization':{'name':'Pete's Pet Pagoda','parent_id':'1052385'}}` is not valid JSON. JSON needs double quotes for keys and string values.

Comment: I have changed the json in the answer from the above as it was wrong

Comment: https://onlinedevtools.in/curl sends your curl command to their server, so remove any sensitive data from your curl command before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `body`, not `multipart`. You can also use `json`.

```
$request = $client->request('POST',
            self::$baseUrl.'/organizations', [
            'headers' => [
                'x-app-key'   => self::$appKey,
                'x-user-key'  => self::$userKey,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'body' => [
                '{"organization":
                      [
                          {
                              "name":"Pete`s Pet Pagoda",
                              "parent_id":"1052385"
      
                          }
                      ]
                 }',
            ],
        ]);
```

### method 2

You can pass array to the json request option and it will convert it to json when sending the guzzle request. No need to use header as application/json as it applies internally.

```
$client->request('POST',
            self::$baseUrl.'/organizations', [
            'headers' => [
                'x-app-key'   => self::$appKey,
                'x-user-key'  => self::$userKey,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'json' => [
                "organization" => [
                         [
                             "name" => "Pete`s Pet Pagoda"
                             "parent_id" => "1052385"
                         ]
                ]
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: That's still not valid JSON. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @El_Vanja,  I've tried doing something similar to @bhucho 's example as a predefined associative array outside of the `$client->request()` and used `json_encode()` on it which created a valid json string. Still I received the same error as mentioned above in my original post.

Comment: @GhostHunterJim Oh, I've never meant to imply this was the source of the error. Just pointing it out in case someone comes across this and tries to use it as is.

Comment: @GhostHunterJim what is the error you are getting, have you removed the multipart which you were writing, you can write it another way as well

Comment: @bhucho -  The error I am ( or rather was ) getting is shown at the bottom of my original post but I'll post it here as well, `curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE*`.  However, I've fixed the issue since I last posted here. I'll update my OP.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. For further debugging use Middleware::tap(find more help here [middleware+json+request](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json))

```
try{
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', self::$baseUrl.'/organizations', 
                [
                    'headers' => [
                        'x-app-key'   => self::$appKey,
                        'x-user-key'  => self::$userKey,
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    ],
                   'json' => [
                        'organization' => 
                        [
                            "name" => "some_name_value",
                            "parent_id" => "id_here",
                            "custom_id" => "custom id here"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]);
   $_response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
}
catch(BadResponseException $e){
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $errorArray = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($errorArray);

    //return some message from errorarray;
}
```